# Account linking Google actions via api.api

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

We are using api.api with fulfillment
After asking to sign in with the code:
    app.askForSignIn();

We get intent call for input.unknown
We added sign handler but it is not called

```
    const SIGN_IN = 'sign.in';
    actionMap.set(SIGN_IN, signInLogic);

    function signInLogic(app) {
            let intent = app.getIntent();
            console.log('signInLogic start intent: ', intent);
    }
```

What needs to define in api.ai as intent to get the correct intent call?
I could not find a place to define system intents

Comment: `input.unknown` is called through the Default Fallback Intent. When you no intent matches the query. 

Your question is very vague..

Comment: Did you follow the documented instructions: https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/account-linking